# Optional scopes in oauth2 omniauth.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

To authenticate users, I am using omniauth-google-oauth2 gem in rails.

Now I want to provide additional google api functionality, but I don't want to make it mandatory. But I can't figure out a way to make a specific scope optional.

I tried adding another entry in omniauth.rb, but it seems that it doesn't allow me to add multiple entries for the same provider (google_oauth2).

Is there a way to add any optional scopes in the rails application?

Comment: Did you find better solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `name` option for that. This should work with any OmniAuth provider:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', {
    :name => 'google'
  }

  provider :google_oauth2, 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', {
    :name => 'google_full',
    :scope => 'original_scope, extra_scope'
  }
end
```

With omniauth-google-oauth2 though, you can take another approach:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', {
    :name => 'google'
  }

  provider :google_oauth2, 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET', {
    :name => 'google_full',
    :scope => 'extra_scope',
    :prompt => 'consent',
    :include_granted_scopes => 'true'
  }
end
```

Check out [Google's Incremental Authorization guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth) for additional details.

Be aware though, that by changing the `name` of the provider, the OmniAuth URL will change to `/auth/new_name` and `request.env['omniauth.auth']['provider']` will then return `new_name`.